# ElasticSearch - Average aggregation/sort over multivalued non-unique numeric fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to handle sorting over the average of multivalued field called 'rating_average'. In the example I'm giving you, the values for this field are [1, 2, 2]. I'm expecting the average to be (1+2+2)/3 = 1.66666667. The reality I'm getting 1.5 as an average.

After a few tests and analyzing extended stats, I've discovered that happens because the average is calculated over all non-unique items. So statistical operators are applied over the set [1, 2] instead of [1, 2, 2]. I've proved this end also by adding an aggregations section to my query to double check the average calculated for the sort block is identical to the one in the stats aggregation.

An example document is the following:

```
{
  "_source": {
  "content_uri": "http://data.semint.co.uk/resource/testContent1",
  "rating_average": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "2"
  ],
  "forDesk": "http://data.semint.co.uk/resource/kMFMJd1rtKD"
}
```

The query I'm performing is the following:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "aggs": {
  "rating_stats": {
    "extended_stats": {
        "field": "rating_average"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "mediaType": [
                  "http://data.semint.co.uk/resource/testMediaType3"
              ],
              "execution": "and"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [ "content_uri", "rating_average"],
  "sort": [
    {
      "rating_average": {
        "order": "desc",
        "mode": "avg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And these are the results I get from executing the query over the document aforementioned.

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "travel_content6",
        "_type": "semantic-index",
        "_id": "http://data.semint.co.uk/resource/testContent1",
        "_score": null,
        "fields": {
          "content_uri": [
            "http://data.semint.co.uk/resource/testContent1"
          ],
          "rating_average": [1, 2, 2]
        },
        "sort": [
          1.5
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "rating_stats": {
      "count": 2,
      "min": 1,
      "max": 2,
      "avg": 1.5,
      "sum": 3,
      "sum_of_squares": 5,
      "variance": 0.25,
      "std_deviation": 0.5,
      "std_deviation_bounds": {
        "upper": 2.5,
        "lower": 0.5
      }
    }
  }
}
```